# Removal of in-app purchase product in itunes connect

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I want to change the type of in-app purchase from auto-renewable to non-consumable one.
So I remove the in-app purchase product in itunes connect and create a new one.
The problem is when restoring, does old users who had ever purchased the auto-renewable receive the old transactions back?

I have another problem now. >_<
1. I remove the old auto-renewable product.
2. Add a new non-consumable product.
3. Add a update version of my app.(ex. 1.3.0)
When I try to test in-app purchase with new product in sandbox, I receive 21004 when I verify the receipt with app-store. I cannot find any definition of error 21004 on non-consumable product.
Only auto-renewable product defines it. It means shared-key not match.
But receipt verification of non-consumable product didn't need shared-key.

Does someone teach me what happen?
Thanks.

Comment: will the product id be the same?

Comment: Nope. Two products with two different product id.

Comment: To avoid confusion, mainly for yourself, you should use another name.

Comment: @meaning-matters Do you mean app name or product identifier?

Comment: I'm speaking of the product identifier... but if the product identifier **will** be different, how would you like to expect that the _new_ product identifier can be restorable for a user who _never_ purchased it before?

Comment: @holex I just wonder if old customers who had ever bought auto-renewable products will receive transactions which belong to old product. Of course they will not receive transactions they never purchased.

Comment: @meaning-matters Absolutely I use the different one. Apple will not allow developers to reuse deleted product identifiers.